Conection NginX and Reactfrontend
I'm working on a project for my degree. The next step is that I want to build a connection between my React app and the Nginx server. Both are in separate Docker containers. My current status is that when I open localhost, the request is forwarded to the right index.html in the frontend. However, I only get a white page displayed because it can't find the main.jsx anymore. Since I'm new to this topic and don't really know my way around, I wanted to ask you for advice. Thank you in advance.
My Dockerfile for the frontend folder:

FROM node:14 as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
#RUN npm install bootstrap

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/ /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]


My nginx.conf:

worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    sendfile on;

    upstream frontend {
        server frontend:80;
    }

    upstream backend {
        server backend:8888; 
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        # Handle frontend
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }



The important parts of the docker compose:

 nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
    networks:
      - backend
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: frontend
    expose:
      - "80"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

In my local environment the react app works

"it can't find the main.jsx anymore" – how have you built the React app? A built app shouldn't have a JSX file.

Hey thanks for the answer. Yes, I have built a React app with Vite. The Main.jsx file was already there and I didn't change it at all. If I run the React app without Docker and normally with "npm run dev", everything works. The page is then displayed.

Well, what does your browser's console or network inspector say? Likely a 404, I'd imagine. You should also just copy the dist folder, not the source code: COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

Loading of the module from ‘http://localhost/src/main.jsx’ was blocked due to an unreleased MIME type (‘application/octet-stream’). Is the Error message. I have no dist folder in my project. I createt one and but everything important in it but sadly that couldnt solve the problem as well.

As said, you shouldn't have a JSX file in a built app. npm run build should create a dist/ directory within the image, you shouldn't create one by hand.

It build an '/build' folder. I tried to Copy from the 'app/build/' folder, but the result is the same. As I said i didnt creat the .jsx file. Should i trie to creat a React Project with an other React Build?

No, vite is fine. Sorry I meant build with dist. You're still not being very clear about what's not working exactly, so it's hard to help. You should make sure the npm run build -built site works outside Docker, then dockerize it.

Thanks for your help so far :) I will try my best to explain what I mean. The problem was that when I tried to access https://localhost, I only saw a white page, and in the browser tab, I saw the title of my index.html. In the browser console, I got the error: "http://localhost:3000/src/main.jsx was blocked due to an unshared MIME type ('text/html')." However, when I started the React app without the Dockerfile and only in the frontend folder, everything worked fine. So I assume the problem is that it can't open main.jsx or access is denied.

Now I tried to create a new React app with 'npx create-react-app frontend' and changed nothing in the settings, just edited the files. I still get the error: "Loading the module from http://localhost:3000/src/main.jsx was blocked due to an unshared MIME type ('text/html')." in my browser console. But suddenly the content of main.js is displayed. The only change I can recognize is that it's now a .js file. Please correct any spelling errors.

Please do not use create-react-app, it's old, slow and generally not recommended anymore. Use Vite. Again, if your built app attempts to somehow use src/main.jsx, something is absolutely wrong.

Ive created a new vite app and now everything is working fine thanks a lot.
